# Creating database cursor for SQL Server 2000 in Django throws ProgrammingError: SYSDATETIME Is Not A Recognized Function Name

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I have to hook a modern Django application up to a very old version of SQL Server 2000. I don't need to be creating/inserting/selecting records; I just need to pass XML to a stored procedure.

I've created an entry in the `settings.py` file for the SQL Server instance I must connect to. I'm getting weird behavior in the interactive shell when I try to create a cursor.

Weirdly, the first time I create the cursor, Django throws an error. The second time, the cursor creates successfully and I can execute my stored procedure.

```py
django.db import connections

cursor = connections['sqlServer2000'].cursor()

 File "/Users/qotsa42/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/qotsa42/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 196, in connect
    self.init_connection_state()
  File "/Users/qotsa42/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 362, in init_connection_state
    val = cursor.execute('SELECT SYSDATETIME()').fetchone()[0]
  File "/Users/qotsa42/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 546, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]'SYSDATETIME' is not a recognized function name. (195) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Weirdly, when I try to create the cursor again, it works and i have no issues.

```py
>>> from django.db import connections
>>> cursor = connections['sqlServer2000'].cursor()

 File "/Users/qotsa42/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/qotsa42/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 196, in connect
    self.init_connection_state()
  File "/Users/qotsa42/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 362, in init_connection_state
    val = cursor.execute('SELECT SYSDATETIME()').fetchone()[0]
  File "/Users/qotsa42/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 546, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]'SYSDATETIME' is not a recognized function name. (195) (SQLExecDirectW)")
>>> cursor = connections['sqlServer2000'].cursor()
>>> cursor
<django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x10532e1c0>
```

Any ideas what might be causing this? I suppose I could do something hacky as a workaround, but I'd rather figure out what's causing the issue:

```py
>>> from django.db import connections
>>> try:
...     cursor = connections['sqlServer2000'].cursor()
... except:
...     cursor = connections['sqlServer2000'].cursor()
```

My first thought is that this is either a bug in Pyodbc or Django.

Comment: Django's connection initialization is fetching some system information.  If you do a dummy query in a `try`/`except`/`pass`, I'm guessing your other queries will work.

Comment: There is no `sysdatetime()` function in SQL Server 2000, it first appeared in 2005. You may try to replace it with `getdate()` if it's possible, although I doubt it's somehow related to the Django's behaviour. Still, might be worth a try.

Comment: @RogerWolf yeah for some reason it looks like pyodbc is trying to call `sysdatetime()` when it initializes the database connection even though the TDS protocol I'm using is 7.1, which is the recommended protocol for SQL Server 2000.

Comment: It isn't the TDC protocol that's a problem. It is the functionality implemented within the library that assumes (and therefore requires - at least implicitly) a certain level of tsql functionality that is not available in sql server 2000. You need an environment that supports 2000 - and that is not likely to exist 20 years later using any current version of python / django.